# Statistical method used to compare internet speed

Tags: probability, statistics

A cable provider received a complaint from a customer. The
customer is complaining that the internet service is too low. The
cable company servicer measured the internet speed at two locations
in the house at the cable box and in the living room. He did 8
measurements at each location. The recorder measurements are in the
table below.

[image]

It is expected to lose 15% of internet speed from the cable box
to the living room.

Redo the table by dropping the internet speed measurements at
cable box for 15% percent. Then compare the two location
measurement using appropriate statistical method.

What statistical method did you use?

Is there enough statistical evidence to accept the methods
results as significant? Explain.

What is the final conclusion?

**Note: Must use only this statistical method:
**Linear Regression**

Comment: FYI: There's also a stack exchange site devoted to stats: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a straightforward regression problem. On our site, you are expected to show what you have tried. If you have difficulty, perhaps we can be of help.